# Scala Spark RDD.groupBy where each element can be in multiple groups

Tags: scala, apache-spark, group-by, rdd

Say I have a list of multiples and a list of factors (both Int):

```
val multiples = sc.parallelize(List(1,2,3,4,5,6))
val factors = List(1,2,3)
```

I want to use groupBy on multiples to return a List[(Int, Iterable[Int])] such that each pair represents a factor, and all the multiples of that factor in multiples. Like so:

```
(1, Iterable(1,2,3,4,5,6))
(2, Iterable(2,4,6))
(3, Iterable(3,6))
```

The problem is that groupBy does not seem to be able to duplicate elements across groups. Is that true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `flatMap` on the rdd; for each element, collect factors that are divisor of the specific element which would be duplicated based on how many factors satisfy the condition; finally use `groupByKey` to collect elements belonging to the same factor:

```
multiples.flatMap(x => factors.collect{ case i if x % i == 0 => (i, x) }).groupByKey.collect

// res4: Array[(Int, Iterable[Int])] = Array((1,CompactBuffer(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)), 
//                                           (2,CompactBuffer(2, 4, 6)), 
//                                           (3,CompactBuffer(3, 6)))
```